# Return and finally clause - inconsistent behaviour

Tags: c#, .net

I came across slightly odd (IMO) code whcih behaves inconsistantly.

```
try
{
   if (helperMethod())
   {
       return 0;
   }

   return 0;
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
    // Log and throw
 }
 finally
 {
     // Do a lot of stuff after value has been returned
 }
```

This sits inside a method which gets called by a VBA through by passing COM object to my DLL. When it just runs, I don't get exception in C#, but I get a VBA exception.

When I run this in a debug than I don't get exception anywhere.

My guess is that logic in a finally clause takes over a second to run, and at that time 0 has already been returned by main body of the method.

I can re-write this in few ways, but I don't knwo whether it's common to write code in such a way...?

Thank you

**EDIT:** Could it be that the COM object gets released when I return 0? In that case it's no longer available in a finally clause.

Comment: All code in the finally block will be executed _before_ this function returns.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Do you mean that it will get to return statment, pause, execute everything in a finally clause and then proceed with a return?

Comment: Yes, the return statement establishes the return value but the function is exited 'through' the finally block.

Comment: If it helps, imagine that the `return 0;` was actually `return SomeFunctionThatItselfReturnsAnInt();` - in that case, the following would happen: 1) `SomeFunctionThatItselfReturnsAnInt` would be run and the value it returned "stored" 2) The code in the `finally` would run 3) The value stored in (1) would be returned as the result of your method

Comment: That all makes sense, I'm going to work on this for a bit longer to find out why the code executes sucessfully in debug mode (sometimes).

Comment: Problem wasn't in the COM objects, had to re-write logic in a method and it all works. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here you may be trying (no pun intended) to use the finally block in an odd way. The Framework documentation typifies finally as follows:

> The finally block is useful for cleaning up any resources allocated in the try block.

You should do your work within your try block (or outside the try-catch-finally construct if it's just covering a potential exception condition and not the subsequent processing of returned data) and your finally block should only release any resources allocated in the try that need to be released regardless of an exception or normal termination.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I completely agree with you. This is not my code and logic in finally goes over quite a few lines which I don't like myself. I need to understand whether COM object gets released on some logic gets executed too early, or doesn't get executed at all.

Comment: I guess my point is that you shouldn't spend too long trying to get to the bottom of that argument but rather spend the time rewriting the code and getting yourself into a clearly predictable piece of source (as well as one can predict any execution path).

Comment: Problem was indeed in the logic, had to re-write that, it all works now. Thanks

Comment: @Henk Holterman : I realised that I wasn't answering his specific problem but it looked as though there was an edge-case here. It's easy to get caught up in the error and miss the obvious point that the code smells bad. The code smell should always be addressed first, if nothing else it makes finding the actual bug easier if it hasn't eliminated it already.

Answer (score 2):

COMException can crash your .NET CLR engine so that engine does not get a chance to run the finally code. In these cases you will see an entry in the EventLog.

I have seen a lot of these with WMI. *Evil, evil ...*

Comment: Entry in the EventLog, did you mean EventViewer? If not, than where do I find it?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this has been resolved. I had to re-write entire method.